# asp link with a QueryString value

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have a List of Names wrapped in a LinkButton like this

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="link_nombre_paciente_espera" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Default.aspx?id=<%#Eval('id')%>" Text=' <%#Eval("name") %>' ID="name" />
```

But it doesnt work. When i click on it in the url  appears:

```
Default.aspx?id=<%#Eval('id')%>
```

How can i fix that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:LinkButton PostBackUrl="Default.aspx?id=<%#Eval('id')%>" Text='<%#Eval("name")%>' />
```

There was typo. It was just PostBackUr.

Comment: No, it doesnt work. Is there another way to fill and gridview with data without a query string? I mean, if i click in the link, it will fill it with the id that in giving. For example: passing the ID as a parameter to a function...

Comment: @EinerSantanaR but your original question is about wrong url. isnt it?

Comment: no, its about how can i pass values through the url with a query string insert in a linkbutton...

Comment: @EinerSantanaR you are also missing runat="server"

Comment: i sorry that i didnt copy the real code, I'll edit and post the original code(i already have runat="server" in my code)

Comment: @EinerSantanaR do you have id property?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25222/discussion-between-ashreva-and-einer-santana-r)

Comment: @EinerSantanaR Problem resolved http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/311314-How-pass-multiple-querystring-linkbutton-gridview.aspx
Accept answer if everything is ok now

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping the double quotes like you have for the text

```
'Default.aspx?id=<%#Eval("id")%>'
```

instead of

```
"Default.aspx?id=<%#Eval('id')%>"
```